# Which episode(s) of the Jackie Chan adventures featured a female sumo wrestler?

Tags: episode-identification, jackie-chan-adventures

I'm sure I saw a female sumo wrestler in one or more of the episodes. Toru bumps into her during a sumo wrestling convention?

All my attempts at googling have failed, and just bring up Toru himself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

She wasn't a wrestler (which is why your Google search failed) but a cosplayer known only as [Sumo Girl](https://jackiechanadventures.fandom.com/wiki/Sumo_Girl):

[image: Sumo Girl: a large black haired woman with vaguely Asian/Chinese clothing]

She only appeared in Season 5 Episode 7.